# Shared socket object among Perl threads

Tags: multithreading, perl, sockets

I am trying to create a socket object that can be shared among threads. The following code does not work because socket object is a GLOB. How could the socket object be shared? Can it be done this way?

```
my $socket1 = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Proto    => "tcp",
        PeerAddr => "localhost",
        PeerPort => "888",
    ) or die "couldn't connect: $!";

my $socket_shared =shared_clone($socket1);
....    
my $thr1 = threads->create(\&Thread_1); 

$thr1->join();

sub Thread_1 {

lock($socket_cpy);

my $data = "Msg.\n";
$socket1->send($data);
$socket1->recv($data,1024);

}
```

ERROR: Unsupported ref type: GLOB at line (7 here, where the shared_clone is called).

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Unsupported ref type: GLOB at line XX (where the shared_clone is).

Comment: The documentation recommends two things; Share the variable before assigning it, and only scalars, arrays, and hashes are supported - so store your socket in a hashref or array object.

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest instead that you *don't* try and share a socket between threads? That feels like something that's going to be asking for concurrency issues between them.

Whilst there are (probably) ways of doing that, I'd suggest instead - have a single thread 'responsible' for the IO, and use something like `Thread::Queue` to interact with it.

E.g. something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
my $output_q = Thread::Queue->new();

my $nthreads = 1;

sub socket_thread {

    my $socket1 = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        Proto    => "tcp",
        PeerAddr => "localhost",
        PeerPort => "888",
    ) or die "couldn't connect: $!";

    while ( my $data = $output_q->dequeue() ) {
        $socket1->send($data);
        $socket1->recv( $data, 1024 );
    }
}


sub worker_thread {
    $output_q->enqueue( "Some text from thread: ",
        threads->self->tid(), "\n" );
}

for ( 1 .. $nthreads ) {
    threads->create( \&worker_thread );
}

foreach my $thr ( threads->list() ) {
    $thr->join();
}
```

That way you don't need to pass the socket around at all, you can use one or more queues to serialise your IO. This - to my mind - is one of the stronger reasons to thread in perl in the first place - you've better IPC mechanisms to work with.

Otherwise I'd be tempted to suggest using forks, which (on Unix) are generally more efficient.