# How to share socket hash to thread function in perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, sockets

I have tried to share hash value to thread function. The hash values contain soket connection , But I didn't share the hash variable to thread function. I am getting `Invalid value for shared scalar` error. But when I assign normal text or integer values to the hash , that time the hash variable  able to share to thread function. Can any one please solve the problem ? Below code I have tried

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Select;
use JSON ;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my  $i=5 ;
my  ($Main_Socket_Hash,$Read_Client );
$|=1;




print "Calling" ;

my ($Chat_Details ) ;

($main::Server,$main::Port)=("192.168.12.37","6666");


$main::Socket= IO::Socket::INET->new(
        'LocalAddr' =>  $main::Server,
        'LocalPort' =>  $main::Port,
        'Proto'     =>  'tcp',
        'Listen'    =>  '120' ,
        'Reuse'     =>  1
        ) ;

Handle_Client() ;

sub Handle_Client {

    my ( $New_Socket,$New_Client,@Ready_Clints,$Thread_Id )   ;


    share($i) ;
    shared($Main_Socket_Hash) ;
    $Thread_Id=threads->create(\&Read_Outgoing_Message);

    $Read_Client = new IO::Select() ;
    $Read_Client->add($main::Socket) ;


    while ( 1 )  {

        print "Main loop \n" ;
        my ($Read_Sockets) = IO::Select->select($Read_Client, undef, undef, 0);
        foreach $New_Socket (@$Read_Sockets) {
            Process_Request($New_Socket) ;
        }
        sleep(1);
        $i=$i+5 ;

    }

}


sub Process_Request {
    my (  $New_Socket,$New_Client,$Request_Api ) =@_ ;

    if ( $New_Socket eq $main::Socket ) { 
        $New_Client=$New_Socket->accept();
        $Read_Client->add($New_Client ) ;
    }
    else {
        $Request_Api=<$New_Socket> ;

        unless ( $Request_Api ) { 
            $Read_Client->remove($New_Socket) ;
            close($New_Socket) 
        }
        else {
            chomp($Request_Api );
            Validation_Request_Api($New_Socket,$Request_Api)  ;

        }

    }

}


sub  Validation_Request_Api {

    my ( $New_Socket, $Request_Api ,$Request_Data ) = @_ ;

    $Request_Data=decode_json($Request_Api) ;
    unless ( $Request_Data )
    {
        return "FAILURE" ;
    }
    unless ( $Main_Socket_Hash->{$Request_Data->{'chatId'}} )
    {
        $Main_Socket_Hash->{$Request_Data->{'chatId'}}=$New_Socket; 
        #$Main_Socket_Hash->{$Request_Data->{'chatId'}}=$Request_Data->{'chatId'}; 
    }

    return "SUCCESS" ;
}
sub Read_Outgoing_Message {


    my ( $Status,$Outgoing_Message )  ;

    while ( 1 )  {
        print "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%===> $i <=====%%%%%%%%%%%%%\n" ;
        print "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%===> " . Dumper ( $Main_Socket_Hash) ."  <=====%%%%%%%%%%%%%\n" ;
        sleep ( 1) ;

    }
}
```

**Note :**
When I get error  while assigning socket connection to hash value

```
 $Main_Socket_Hash->{$Request_Data->{'chatId'}}=$New_Socket;
```

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=473566 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852180/shared-socket-object-among-perl-threads

Comment: Whether is it possible to share socket connection to the client ?  I want to share hast value to the thread but the hash value contain multiple client socket connection.